# How to control the auto rotate by a Button in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, autorotate

I am develop in `Objective-C`

I using the following code to lock the `screen orientation` and set it to `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

But I want to lock the `screen rotate` dynamic by a `UIButton`. For example , If the current `shouldAutorotate` is `No`. It will change to the `YES` when I click the `Button`. Like the following pseudo code.

```
- (IBAction) lock_Auto_rotate:(id)sender {

    if(Autorotate == YES){
       Autorotate = NO;
    }else{
       Autorotate = YES;
    }
}
```

**How to control the `auto rotate` by a `Button` ?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track, just need to do some manipulation.
Take a look at below code snippet.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
if (isRotateOn) 
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
else
 {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
 if (isRotateOn) 
 {
    return YES;
 }
 else
 {
    return NO;
 } 
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

 if (isRotateOn)
 {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
 }
 else
 {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
 }

}

-(IBAction)btnRotateOnOffAction:(id)sender
{

if ([self.btnRotateOnOff.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"On"])
{
    isRotateOn =YES;
    [self.btnRotateOnOff setTitle:@"Off" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
else
{
    isRotateOn = NO;
    [self.btnRotateOnOff setTitle:@"On" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


}

}


Let me know if you have any queries.
```